# What's wrong with my Fibonacci implementation?

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I'm trying to transform my recursive Fibonacci function into an iterative solution. I tried the following:

```hs
fib_itt :: Int -> Int
fib_itt x = fib_itt' x 0
where
    fib_itt' 0 y = 0
    fib_itt' 1 y = y + 1
    fib_itt' x y = fib_itt' (x-1) (y + ((x - 1) + (x - 2)))
```

I want to save the result into variable `y` and return it when the `x` `y` matches with `1` `y`, but it doesn't work as expected. For `fib_itt 0` and `fib_itt 1`, it works correctly, but for `n > 1`, it doesn't work. For example, `fib_rek 2` returns `1` and `fib_rek 3` returns `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong: in `y + (x-1) + (x-2)` you only add up consecutive numbers - not the numbers in the fib.series.

It seems like you tried some kind of *pair-approach* (I think) - and yes it's a good idea and can be done like this:

```
fib :: Int -> Int
fib k = snd  $ fibIt k (0, 1)

fibIt :: Int -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
fibIt 0 x = x
fibIt k (n,n') = fibIt (k-1) (n',n+n')
```

as you can see: this passes the two needed parts (the last and second-to-last number) around as a pair of numbers and keeps track of the iteration with `k`.

Then it just gives back the second part of this tuple in `fib` (if you use  the first you will get `0,1,1,2,3,...` but of course you can adjust the initial tuple as well if you like (`fib k = fst  $ fibIt k (1, 1)`).

---

by the way this idea directly leeds to this nice definition of the fib.sequence if you factor the iteration out to `iterate` ;)

```
fibs :: [Int]
fibs = map fst $ iterate next (1,1)
       where
         next (n,n') = (n',n+n')

fib :: Int -> Int
fib k = fibs !! k
```